# Do schema of database change with an entry

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am currently studying database as my core subject in my institute. I was going through some basic concepts of database and I found this written [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/vihangamorg/dbms)

> The description of  a database is also called Schema. Schema are frequently changed when any entry in database is added or deleted .

According to my knowledge schema is the definition of a database and changes infrequently. It is sort of a structure description of a database just like a blueprint, whereas entry is process of entering data into the database, so how can it affect the schema of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: a schema is a structural definition which changes infrequently due to the difficulty of applying changes. It certainly doesn't change every time you write data. However, "entry" is not really a technical term. You're taking it to mean a record in a table, which is what I'd generally expect too. It looks as if the author of those notes speaks English as a second or later language and is using it to mean a structural component like a table or view (in technical terms, a *relation*). This is the first time I've seen this usage, and I wouldn't follow it because most people will, like you, think entry = record.

Comment: First things first, I really appreciate someone gave an answer after three day. That statement was really confusing.